# How do I debug omni-auth2 client and provider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0

How do I debug omni-auth2 apps?

One example of such pair is here:
https://github.com/webgoal/spike-oauth-rails52

How do I debug problems with configuration. I need to find out if the client is really talking to the provider and if so what response it gets, 401 code does not help in fixing the app.

Answer (score 0):

I had success editing the gems and inserting byebug here and there. Cloning the gem code and using my editor to grep the codebase was another valuable aid.